# Google market и геолокации

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Я живу в Крыму и не могу ничего купить в Google market. Как мне изменить геолокацию на своём смартфоне?  Есть несколько программ которые я уже пробовал. Фейковую геолокацию после смены видят все приложения погоды, карты и т.д. Но когда я захожу в google account то там отображается по прежнему моё реальное место положение(((

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.